# Replacing characters in Java

Tags: java, character-encoding, replace

I tried to replace characters in String which works sometimes and does not work most of the time.

I tried the following:

```
String t = "[javatag]";
String t1 = t;
String t2 = t;
t.replace("\u005B", "");
t.replace("\u005D", "");
t1.replace("[", "");
t1.replace("]", "");
t2.replace("\\]", "");
t2.replace("\\[", "");
System.out.println(t+" , "+t1+" , "+t2);
```

The resulting output is still "`[javatag] , [javatag] , [javatag]`" without the "[" and "]" being replaced.

What should I do to replace those "[" and "]" characters ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings are immutable so

```
t.replace(....);
```

does nothing

you need to assign the output to some variable like

```
t = t.replace(....);
```

Comment: +1 You gave him `t`, I gave `t1` and Brian `t2`. I think he is all set :)

Comment: hilarious, all within 4 seconds of eachother too

Comment: I can't decide if it's funny ... or sad. :-D

Comment: I see your `replace()` and I raise you a `replaceAll()`

Comment: And sadly ... it didn't win the day.

Comment: Didn't make Al Gore feel any better either.

Answer (score 7):

`String` objects in java are immutable. You can't change them.

You need:

```
t2 = t2.replace("\\]", "");
```

`replace()` returns a new `String` object.

**Edit: Because ... I'm breaking away from the pack**

And since this is the case, the argument is actually a regex, and you want to get rid of both brackets, you can use `replaceAll()`  instead of two operations:

```
t2 = t2.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
```

This would get rid of both opening and closing brackets in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 4):

`String`s in Java are immutable, meaning you can't change them. Instead, do `t1 = t1.replace("]", "");`. This will assign the result of `replace` to t1.

Answer (score 2):

String.replace doesn't work that way. You have to use something like `t = t.replace("t", "")`

Answer (score 1):

String.replace() returns a new string after replacing the required characters. Hence you need to do it in this way:

```
String t = "[javatag]";
t = t.replace("[","");
t = t.replace("]","");
```

Comment: I see. I just forgot to escape the special characters. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I have just checked the code and I found it is working without escaping the string.

Comment: Actually - you're right because I think it's calling `replace(char, char)`. I forgot there was that overload.

Answer (score 0):

```
t.replace(....);
```

gives you a String (return a string)

you can reassign the origin variable name to the new string

and the old string will later been garbage-collected
:)